# Why the memory consumption with and without __slots__ is same?

Tags: python

I was trying to understand use of **slots** in Python, so I created two classes, one with **slots** and one without it, then, I created about a million objects and print the size of both the objects:

```
>>> class Foo(object): pass
>>> class Bar(object): __slots__ = ()
>>> foos = [Foo() for f in xrange(1000000)]
>>> bars = [Bar() for b in xrange(1000000)]
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(foos)
4348732
>>> sys.getsizeof(bars)
4348732
```

Surprisingly both the objects are of same size. So now I am confused why is it said that **slots** save memory ?

P.S. I tried this on Linux, Python 2.7

This is not duplicate of:
[Usage of __slots__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots)

Here I want to know why the memory consumption in both the scenarios is same?

Comment: You are comparing sizes of lists that only contain references to instances. Try `sys.getsizeof(bars[0])` and `sys.getsizeof(foos[0])` instead.

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30047388/2301450